# Interpretation of Right-Handed and Left-Handed Systems via a Corkscrew

Tags: coordinate-systems

[image]

[image]

I am confused about how this explanation on the right-handed and left-handed system uses the angle of the direction of the turn and the direction turned through. Can anyone try to clarify visually what this angle they are referring to is? I am familiar with what the orientation of the xyz coordinate system would look for both systems, but I wanted to further understand it in the lens of this corkscrew analogy. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your fault; this is confusingly written. For 'move' in the second line of para 2, read 'move translationally' or simply 'translate'. When the writer talks about OC making an acute angle with "this direction", (s)he means the direction of translation when the corkscrew is turned as described at the beginning. Hope this helps.

Simple example ... Take an ordinary right handed cartesian system but reorientate the z axis so that it's on the same side of the x-y plane, but not at right angles to it.

Let $\overrightarrow {OA}$ be the $x$ axis, $\overrightarrow {OB}$ be the $y$ axis, $\overrightarrow {OC}$ be the new $z$ axis. Turning the corkscrew handle through the acute angle from being aligned with $\overrightarrow {OA}$ to being aligned with $\overrightarrow {OB}$, will make the corkscrew translate in the the usual, right-handed cartesian, z direction). Since there is an acute angle between the translation direction and the new z direction, $\overrightarrow {OC}$, we still have a right-handed system.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation really helped visualize what was going on ^_^